# How to grab different sort of images from it's src using wget?

Tags: linux, image, web-crawler, scrapy, wget

This is an example image src. I want to save this image using wget. How to do that?

```
http://lp.hm.com/hmprod?set=key[source],value[/environment/2013/2BV_0002_007R.jpg]&set=key[rotate],value[-0.1]&set=key[width],value[3694]&set=key[height],value[4319]&set=key[x],value[248]&set=key[y],value[354]&set=key[type],value[FASHION_FRONT]&hmver=0&call=url[file:/product/large]
```

Comment: I suggest moving this to Unix & Linux as it's not a programming question.

Comment: I already have tagged it as linux, wget, crawl..what makes you think that it's in programming section?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wget -L "http://lp.hm.com/hmprod?set=key[source],value[/environment/2013/2BV_0002_007R.jpg]&set=key[rotate],value[-0.1]&set=key[width],value[3694]&set=key[height],value[4319]&set=key[x],value[248]&set=key[y],value[354]&set=key[type],value[FASHION_FRONT]&hmver=0&call=url[file:/product/large]" -O zz.jpg

Providing quotes to your link to be downloaded is very essential. This link in particular has many special character capable of screwing things up.